# Use existing encrypted directory as home directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, home-directory, ecryptfs

In the past, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with /dev/sda4 mounted as /home. I encrypted my home directory.

Today, I erased all the partitions except /dev/sda4 and I installed Xubuntu 14.04 on a new partition (/dev/sda3). I did not mount /dev/sda4.

Then I used usermod to change my home directory from /home/jordan to /home-old/jordan. Then I mounted /dev/sda4 as /home.

Now I want to change my current home directory from /home-old/jordan to /home/jordan, keeping the original (encrypted) contents of /home/jordan.

How can I do this? (I know both the login password and the ecryptfs passphrase used to encrypt the old home directory.)